# A tiny shock when using electrical tools, am I safe?

Tags: electrical, safety

I get a little shock when I use a couple of electrical tools in my garage studio. My husband tells me not to worry about it, just wear shoes. He says it is caused by a crossed neutral wire, and that it has been like this forever.
Am I safe working out here with shoes on,  or should I hire a professional electrician to fix it?

Comment: is it just electrostatic charge ? also does it happens when the tool is off ?

Comment: Is this electrical tool a fractal/Lichtenberg wood burner, by any chance?  No, we're not just going to give you a lecture, I for one also have advice.

Answer (score 7):

Oh hell no.  As soon as they trot out the "it's been that way forever" (implying: "and nobody's died so far") claim... they are talking about a genuinely unsafe situation that they know is unsafe, and have an immortality complex.

They are wrong.  People can get bit many times, and then one day conditions are just a little bit wrong because of humidity or something, and then blammo it kills them.

Zero tolerance toward that sort of thing.  At the very least insist on GFCI protection to the whole circuit, which will "keep you honest" in terms of certain wiring flaws.

Now a crossed neutral would start a fire, but it wouldn't shock anyone.

What will shock people is bootlegging ground. When you misuse ground as neutral, it isn't ground anymore. It's neutral.  Which means you have no ground protection and everything that is "grounded" is at neutral voltage, which can be 120v at times. That's why we put insulation on the neutral wire.

Insist on everything being fixed properly.

Comment: neutral can be 120v *if it gets disconnected* (which means a single failure could kill you - you lost redundancy). Any other times?

Answer (score 0):

A little shock means something is wrong. Some day or maybe tomorrow you'll get a big shock. Since hubby knows what's wrong, have him fix it.

Comment: Think this is one job hubby should leave for someone else.  Not much if hubby says just to wear shoes.